# constexpr using standard library algorithms

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, constexpr, dereference

When built using C++17/C++20 x64 gcc/clang, the below snippet yields a compile error whereas de-referencing the iterator directly via `*std::max_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr))` works fine. Any ideas as to why? I've also observed similar behavior with other standard algorithms that have become constexpr since C++20, e.g. `std::upper_bound`

```
int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int,5> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    constexpr auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

```
source>:11:73: error: '(((std::array<int, 5>::const_pointer)(& arr.std::array<int, 5>::_M_elems)) + 16)' is not a constant expression
   11 |     constexpr auto it  = std::max_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
      |
```

Comment: So the problem seems to be _if `std::begin`/ `std::end` are `constexpr`, fed with a `constexpr std::array`, and `std::max_element` is `constexpr`, why can't `std::max_element`'s output be `constexpr` too?_

Comment: Particularly given that ```*std:max_element``` output IS ```constexpr```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`it` has to store a pointer to the element of `arr`.

Since `arr` is not `static`, it's located on the stack, so its address can't be determined at compile-time.

It will work if you make `arr` `static`.

Comment: Interesting, given```*std::max_element``` works, presumably it treats obtaining the iterator and de-referencing it as a single monolithic expression that itself can be constexpr.

Comment: @user3882729 I'm not sure I'd say that. The `std::max_element` call *is* something that can be evaluated at compile-time, "on it's own". But the value resulting from that evaluation is subject to further tests when you try to use it to initialize a `constexpr` variable. The iterator, which has `&arr` "in" it does not pass unless `arr` is `static`, but the dereferenced value is atomic and does pass. The iterator "is `constexpr`" in the sense that it's allowed as an *intermediate* in `constexpr` computation, just not as the result.